# How to sum columns in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, ruby-on-rails-4, sum

```
  <% @cart.items.each do |item| %>
    <div class="holder">

        <div class="image"><%= link_to (image_tag (item.product.avatar.url(:thumb))), item.product %></div>
        <div class="title"><%= link_to item.product.title, item.product %></div>

        <div class="count"><%= item.count %></div>
        <div class="price"><%= number_to_currency(item.product.price, :unit => '€ ') %></div>
        <div class="description"><%= item.product.description.truncate(110).html_safe %></div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="total">Total price: @price</div>
```

I'd like to get the total sum of `item.product.price` column for each `cart` and then display it at the end of the carts list. How can that be done?

Comment: What is @cart? An A::R object or something else?

Comment: @MarkThomas `@cart = Cart.find(session[:cart])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use arel to achieve this, it avoids loading the items and their products so you wont be hit with as many queries as you have items in your cart:

```
@cart.items.joins(:product).sum("products.price")
```

This will lead to a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(products.price) AS sum_id 
FROM `items` 
INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `items`.`product_id` 
WHERE `items`.`cart_id` = 1
```

Comment: This method throws out an error `Association named 'products' was not found on Item; perhaps you misspelled it?`, why so?

Comment: @Xeen sorry, you have to do `joins(:product)`. Edited.